# Do we need the [commercial-application] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [commercial-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commercial-application) tag has 32 questions, no usage guidance, and is mostly off-topic questions.

The tag itself is ambiguous. Almost everything that professional developers work on are technically commercial applications.

It's hard to say whether the tag is definitively on-topic or not because it's so ambiguous, but the current primary usage of the tag appears to be for licensing questions, which is definitely not on-topic.

It would be hard to argue that this tag adds meaningful information to the post or means the same thing in all common contexts. Again, this tag could theoretically refer to almost anything professional developers work on.

Can we burninate this?

Comment: Looks burnable to me. Unless there's any (good) objections, it can be burninated more or less immediately (because it has <50 questions)